# Customising virtuemart cart

Tags: php, html, mysql, joomla, virtuemart

I would like to customise the add to cart and actual checkout processes of the latest version virtuemart and Joomla 2.5.

The first thing i want to do is to change it so that when a product is added to the cart, instead of the JS popup box i want it to redirect straight the the first stage of the checkout.

Then i want to split the checkout into 4 pages starting with the user entering their details, then viewing the cart, payment and confirmation of the order.

I'm not expecting step by step instructions, just pointing the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Just edit the right files. Well, you can't do anything with this answer, can you? Because we don't know anything about the problem. Did you already try anything? If so, where did you get stuck? Or don't you know which files to edit? What is your exact problem?

Comment: i know which files to edit to change the layout of the cart page. Im not sure where the code for the add to cart function is or how i would go about spliting the cart into seperate pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can work like this,

First of all you need to redirect the add to cart  to another page.then go to admin configuration.

VM->configuration->checkout->Display modal popup upon 'Add to cart'  uncheck this.

then you will get first page (step of cart) ie, default_pricelist.php for VM2 and above.
Next step you can achieve with cart controller cart.php.

This step is involving selection of billing and shipping address you can find the files under view/users/ two functions in controller select BT and ST.

Also here you can define new steps by creating layout under cart view and use the cart controller.
The final step including the layout order_done.php

Best of luck.

Comment: I managed to do this in a much easier way. All the pages i want to use as steps where already there i just needed to change the order the user navigates through them. So i changed the automatic redirect on add to cart to redirect to the page where the user adds their details and from there the next steps follow on in the correct order. With some futher customisations it should be working exactly as i want it to! Thanks for your help :)